# angular 2 candeactivate not working with child components

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-guards

I have form in child components and i put child component under parent-component form. I have implemented canDeactivate which is not working  for child component.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent,children:[
  {path:'user/new',component:UserFormComponent,canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]},
  {path:'',component:UserListComponent}
]},
];
```

The following stackblitz example.
[Stackblitz exmaple for candeactivate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imgpg6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Can anyone help me, where i am doing wrong

Comment: You're not getting to `UserFormComponent` `submit` function. Your submit button in `FirstChildComponent` is not doing anything

Comment: [Forked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-54108211) your project to let you see that the `CadDeactivateGuard` is working. But I'm not sure what you're trying to do...